# X-Frame-Options header is not included in the HTTP response for ajax4jsf and richfaces

Tags: richfaces, x-frame-options

For security reason, X-Frame options must be included in http responses of my application. I created a filter class to add X-Frmae-OPTIONS to response.  The x-frame- options included in all app pages, with exception, ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js and richfaces/skin.xcss. These two files show as security risk and x-frame-options is not included.
We are using richface3.3 and Seams and JSF1.2 and java, weblogic12c. 
I'm using OWASP ZAP to scan the application

My questions:

1. Why filter class is ignored? There is a way I can change it?
2. does the upgrade (richface, seams and jsf, etc) resolve this issue? Any other solution?

Thank you for your help

```
 public class XSSFilter implements Filter { 

 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
          FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
   String mode = "SAMEORIGIN";
   //String mode = "DENY";
   HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
   HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;        

    //Clickjacking protection 
   res.setHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", mode);
   res.setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
    chain.doFilter(request, res); 


   }

   public void destroy() {
   }

   public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)  throws ServletException {
   }

 }
```

Comment: Well, did you set the filter up in `web.xml`?

Comment: <!--   The filer in web.xml , XSS filter to Prevent Clickjacking attack-->
       <filter>        
              <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>        
              <filter-class>com.chcf.cams.filter.XSSFilter</filter-class>        
       </filter>

Comment: You also need `filter-mapping`.

Comment: Thank you Makhiel.  I have mapping too                                             <!-- XSS filter-mapping -->
       <filter-mapping>        
              <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>        
              <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   
       </filter-mapping>